# How to pass variable content into modal

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I need to pass variable to modal

The variable is

```
$row['content']
```

My modal

```
<button class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-default" data-id='.$row['content'].' data-toggle="modal" >Edit</button>
```

Script

```
<script>
  $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
  var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
  $(".modal-body #feature").val( myBookId );
  alert(myBookId);
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
</script>
```

**I am getting the first words, No words shown which comes  after space**

Any experts??

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: `$row['content']` is in php ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make little change: ( add **`"`** double quote before and after **`'.$row['content'].'`**  as below: )

```
<button class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-default" 
        data-id="'.$row['content'].'" data-toggle="modal" >
    Edit
</button>
```